# AngularJS canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, draw

I'm trying to make and web application that using AngularJS as front view. I want to make something like a "paint" where you are able to draw something on the screen. The thing is that i want to be able to edit each individual line at any time. By that I mean to be able to delete it or change it's line type or even it's dimensions.
I don't really know if this is possible and I cannot find anything related on the internet. Any kind of information would be appreciated.

Comment: add some wire-frame/prototype with sample code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas is just a dumb drawing surface. It doesn't keep track of lines or polygons or anything like that. You'll need to keep track of them yourself and do your own hit testing to support mouse interaction, redraw the image when necessary, etc. Basically you'd have to build your own vector drawing application on top of the canvas. Fun, but no small feat.

Instead, I recommend checking into the [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) library.

Comment: Thank you. This library is exactly what i needed.